# Alternative to slideUp that moves the div up and then hides?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make an animation for my home garage door opener I wrote to show the garage opening and closing.  So far I have figured out how to draw what I want in html/css(maybe not correctly). Right now I am using `slideUp()`, but it doesn't look that great.  What I really want to happen is for it to slide the margin to 0, then the div to 0.  This works decently on just one of my rectangles, but if I add it to the others, they all run at the same time, even if I do a animate-delay..

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb5jL1k4/15/) so far.

```
$( "#hidebutton" ).click(function() {
  $('.panel').animate({'margin-top': '0'}, 1000);
  $('.panel').animate({'height': '0'}, 1000);
});

$( "#unhidebutton" ).click(function() {
  $('.panel').animate({'margin-top': '15px'}, 1000);
  $('.panel').animate({'height': '30px'}, 1000);
});
```

Also, I don't have a clue how to make it so my button div doesn't slide up, but that isn't as important to me yet..

Comment: Try to use `id`s to identify every rectangles separately instead of class `.panel`.

Comment: CSS `float` `middle` and `top` are invalid values for FLOAT.

Comment: I am doing that in this jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/sb5jL1k4/16/

I just hate using all the setTimeouts, figure there has to be a better way

Comment: I'm unsure what the expected animation is supposed to look like, something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/j5u4swq5/

Comment: I got it working exactly how I want.....but I figure there has to be a better way:
https://jsfiddle.net/sb5jL1k4/20/

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
var duration = 2000; // change as you like
$( "#hidebutton" ).click(function() { 
  var i = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(i === $('.panel').length) clearInterval(timer);
    $('.panel:eq('+i+')').animate({'margin-top': '0'}, 1000).animate({'height': '0'}, 1000);
    i++;
    alert(i);
  } , duration);
});

$( "#unhidebutton" ).click(function() {
  var i = $('.panel').length;
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(i === 0) clearInterval(timer);
    $('.panel:eq('+i+')').animate({'height': '30px'}, 1000).animate({'margin-top': '15px'}, 1000);
    i--;

  } , duration);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/sb5jL1k4/22/)

Comment: That looks like it could do what I want.  I have a version working exactly how I want right here:  https://jsfiddle.net/sb5jL1k4/20/

I'll play around with yours and see if I can get the timing right for me

Comment: @cashman04 your code is too long .. I updated my code with  clearInterval to stop setInterval of continuously work